# Show colors in mode-line for minor modes

Tags: mode-line, projectile, colors

Can't get colors to show up in the mode-line.

```
(eval-after-load "projectile"
  '(setq projectile-mode-line
         '(:eval (concat " Pj["
                         (propertize (projectile-project-name)
                                     'foreground "#81a2be")
                         "]"))))
```

The value gets evaluated correctly, because I see it change in the mode-line when I change pojectile projects, unfortunately it seems that string properties are stripped somewhere down the line. Any ideas how to fix this? Thx

**EDIT** projectile is unlikely to be at fault here cause I tried this with no effect:

```
(eval-after-load "lisp-mode"
  '(defadvice emacs-lisp-mode
       (after rename-modeline activate)
     (setq mode-name
           (propertize "El" 'foreground "#81a2be"))))
```

**SOLUTION** appears that I have been using the wrong property. Thanks to @politza this now works:

```
(eval-after-load "projectile"
  '(setq projectile-mode-line
         '(:eval (list " [Pj:"
                       (propertize (projectile-project-name)
                                   'face '(:foreground "#81a2be"))
                       "]"))))
```

One caveat is that replacing `(list ...)` with `(concat ...)` to actually concatenate strings breaks things. If anyone knows why, I'd be glad to learn.

Comment: Here is a link to a helpful example of how to customize the `mode-line-format` (including, adding coloring):  http://amitp.blogspot.com/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html  Since the `projectile-mode-line` is essentially the value of the minor-mode `:lighter`, you would likely need to customize the `mode-line-format` to achieve the coloring you desire -- i.e., attempting to add color to the value of a `:lighter` is likely the problem in this case.

Comment: > `One caveat is that replacing (list ...) with (concat ...) to actually concatenate strings breaks things. If anyone knows why, I'd be glad to learn. `


       I have observed the same thing. Using `concat` to return a single string with text properties doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong property.

```
,----[ (info "(elisp) Special Properties") ]
|     `face'
|          This property controls the appearance of the text (*note Faces::).
`----
```

Example:

```
(propertize "Foo" 'face '(:foreground "orange"))
```